# Is a name a noun or an adjective?

Tags: nouns, adjectives

I was meditating this morning and this came to me. Hear me out:

A noun is a person, place, thing, or idea.

An adjective on the other hand is something which describes a noun.

My name is Jesse. If my name denotes me, am I the noun or is my name? If my name is the noun, then what happens when I change it? I can't call a building a car but I can call a building hot or cold. If my name is an adjective describing me, why can't I use it on anyone else?

I've read answers on how Shakespeare is a noun while Shakespearean is an adjective. This sort of touches on the issue but doesn't answer it completely.

I could separate me the object from me the idea but I can still describe me the idea with a new name, let's say Jordan, which would be a pen name. My idea stays the same.

Comment: Then the adjective would have to be Jessian. Or Jordanesque.

Comment: You got on the wrong track with "A noun is a person, place, thing, or idea." Assuming you want to explore the linguistic concept of noun, rather than a philosophical one, and you want to specifically define what a noun is in English, rather than what a noun is in general, this just isn't true.

Comment: It's like saying "a cat is a small furry animal with four legs and a tail." It sounds generally correct, but in fact this definition of a cat includes many things that are not cats (e.g. [fossas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fossa_(animal))) and excludes things that are cats (like Sphynx breed cats or cats with one or more amputated limbs). If I say "The fire glows," the word "glows" describes the noun "fire." But "glows" is not an adjective, even though it's used to describe a noun: it is a verb.

Comment: Here are some more accurate tests for identifying the part of speech of English words: https://msu.edu/course/lin/434/PSets/syntactic-categories.pdf

Comment: I can turn a tree into firewood, but the words are nouns which represent the actual things.

Comment: @herisson Thank you for this link. Should it be turned into an answer? Good for people who haven’t taken a course in modern linguistics.

Answer (score 4):

> **Noun** *noun*
>   A word (other than a pronoun) used to identify any of a class of people, places, or things (common noun), or to name a particular one of these (proper noun).
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/noun)

The point of interest here is that a noun is a *word*, not the concept or the object. Consider it a label if you wish. If you change your name, you simply switch labels. You then have a previous name (a noun) and your current name (also a noun).

In your sentence "A noun is a person, place, thing, or idea", the word *is* should be understood as the following:

> **be** *verb*
>   3.3 Represent.
>   ‘let A be a square matrix of order n’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/be)

That is, a noun *represents* the person, place, etc, as opposed to being those things ontologically.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that a noun is a type of adjective then.
But there is confusion because a noun is defined as being a signifier. which indicates a flaw:

If an adjective is describing a noun which is representing something that actually is (being) then calling a noun green when the being which is being represented is green and not the actual noun is inaccurate unless the noun as a word is in fact printed, displayed or presented in green.

Upon doing a search it seems this issue must have been dealt with since I studied this in grammar. Merriam-Webster defines adjective:

A word belonging to one of the major form classes in any of numerous languages and typically serving as a modifier of a noun to denote a 'quality of the thing named', to indicate its quantity or extent, or to specify a thing as distinct from something else

- I added quotations